# Python как обратится к классу изнутри

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Мне нужно распарсить json следующим образом:

```
from jsonmodels.fields import StringField, ListField
from jsonmodels.models import Base

class A_class(Base):
    a = StringField()
    b = StringField()
    c = ListField(A_class)


class AA(Base):
   elements = ListField(A_class)
```

python так не умеет, потому что в этот момент A_class еще не существует.
Пытаюсь сделать это через метаклассы, но не очень понимаю как
(это не работает):

```
class Meta(type):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
     cls.a = StringField()
     cls.b = StringField()
     cls.c = ListField(cls)
     return cls

class A_class(Base):
  __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Мне возвращается:

```
{elements =  [{}, {}, {}]}
```

А должно быть:

```
{'elements' = [{'a':'text', 
                'b':'text',
                'c': [{'a':'text', 'b':'text'}, 
                      {'a':'text', 'b':'text', 
                       'c':['a':'text', 'b':'text']}]}, 
                      {}, {}]}
```

и т. д.

Как сделать нормально?

Comment: Просто `c = ListField('A_class')`

Comment: 1) это не работает 2) почему это вообще должно работать, что это за 'A_class'??? список из строки чтаа 3) c = ListField(A_class) выглядит это обычно так, но python так не умеет, потому что в этот момент A_class еще не существует

Comment: "почему это вообще должно работать" - потому что таким образом реализуется ленивая подгрузка класса в jsonmodels. Вы расскажите, что значит не работает (возможно я накосячил, но по идее должно работать)

Comment: И правда я слегка накосячил. Но вот так точно работает, в этот раз проверил: `c = ListField(['A_class'])`

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Почему в вопросе метка `python3.x` если `__metaclass__` из второго питона?